Google OAuth Signin
Tell me about google sign in in database
Trying to add google OAuth
To differentiate between normal login and Google login in your database, you can add a field to your user model that indicates the method of account creation. Here are the steps:
Add a Field to Indicate Account Type: Add a field like authProvider to your user model. This field can store values like "local" for normal logins and "google" for Google logins.
Update Your User Model: Modify your user model to include this new field.
Update Your Sign-Up and Sign-In Logic: Ensure that when a user signs up or signs in using Google, the authProvider field is set appropriatel
